# C# Get path of files opened in notepad.exe

Tags: c#

I want to get path of all opened files by Notepad.exe
One of the option is using WMIC
wmic process where name="notepad.exe" get name, commandline
You may convert it to C# code using ManagementObjectSearcher
However, it works only when notepad is opened by double clicking a text file. Have you got some better solution?

Comment: How anyone can provide better solution without looking at current code you have done so far? post some code here in question.

Comment: you can make the question easier to read by using commas and periods.

Comment: What is the bigger picture here? What do you want to do?

Comment: I am trying to make a utility which will list all open windows and titles and list of all open files. So for for notepad I could find a WMIC solution only but that worked for only text files which were opened by double clicking. Hope I am clear. Not sure if I paste code here, that would just add complexity.